# How to add tabs to C# tab control programmatically, and add browser and text box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 I'm using C#.

I want to be able to add tabs programmatically when I hit a button in a windows form but I also want to add the web browser component and a textbox to it when a new tab is created.

How can I do this?

I've tried this in the past but to no avail. When switching tabs it would lose all the data of the original tab.

This is what I've used but it doesn't work.:

```
          public Browser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webBrowser.Visible = true;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        webBrowser.Navigate("http://bing.com");
      ///  webBrowser.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Bottom & AnchorStyles.Right & AnchorStyles.Left; 
        tabControl1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Bottom & AnchorStyles.Right & AnchorStyles.Left;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Tab");
        tabControl1.SelectTab(i);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
        i += 1;
    }
```

[Main Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw3ck.jpg)

[Secondary Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NncR4.png)

Comment: Why haven't you created the new instance of `webbrowser`?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this. You maybe forgot to add tabcontrol in the main container.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private WebBrowser webBrowser;
        private TabControl tabControl1;
        private int i = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            createBrowser();
        }

        private void createBrowser()
        {
            webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            tabControl1 = new TabControl();

            webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            webBrowser.Visible = true;
            //webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser.Navigate("http://bing.com");
            ///  webBrowser.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Bottom & AnchorStyles.Right & AnchorStyles.Left;
            tabControl1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Bottom & AnchorStyles.Right & AnchorStyles.Left;
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Tab");
            tabControl1.SelectTab(i);
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
            tabControl1.Size = new Size(500, 300);
            tabControl1.Location = new Point(0, 100);
            i += 1;

            this.Controls.Add(tabControl1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it. How would I go about adding a textbox programmatically? I think that's the issue here.

Comment: Hi, adding text to where? browser component?

Comment: Adding a textbox to the tabcontrol so that it can have it's own URL bar.